# Attempt to check internet connection on iOS device with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, reachability

I use following code to check internet connection:

```
class Reachability {

    let networkReachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.google.com")

    func checkForReachability() {
        self.networkReachabilityManager?.listener = { status in
            print("Network Status: \(status)")
            switch status {
            case .notReachable:
                print("no internet connection detected")
            //Show error here (no internet connection)
            case .reachable(_), .unknown:
                print("internet connection availible")
            }
        }
        self.networkReachabilityManager?.startListening()
    }
}
```

When connection is exist, it successfully call block in .reachable. But in case of connection absence nothing called, why?

I call it like that (keeping reference to class, so it's not released)

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let reachabilityManager = Reachability()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        reachabilityManager.checkForReachability()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: there will be other status cases too use them and debug where its going in your situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create the common class for check the connectivity

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class Connectivity {
    class func isConnectedToInternet() -> Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}
```

and call the function where you need

```
if !Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
    // show Alert
    return
}
```

Comment: Sometimes device is connect to the `Wifi/Mobile data` but internet is not working. So how to check this??

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban - no need of this , alamofire automically recive the value using the key of `isReachable`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik then remove unnecessary code please :)

Comment: @dahiya_boy - this is the one of the method if alamofire, and alomifre automcatically handle this scenario.

Comment: Data is connected but internet is not working. How to check this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a swift class called `Connectivity` . You can use `NetworkReachabilityManager` class from `Alamofire` and configure the `isConnectedToInternet()` method as per your need. I am only checking if the device is connected to internet or not.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
class Connectivity {
    class func isConnectedToInternet() ->Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable
    }
}
```

Usage -

```
if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
        print("Yes! internet is available.")
        // do some tasks..
 }
```

Or you can simply do this -

```
  if let err = error as? URLError, err.code  == URLError.Code.notConnectedToInternet{
    // No internet connection
    }else{
    // your other errors
    }
```